# Count duplicate values in sql server with primary key coloumn

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id(PRIMARY KEY)          item 
---                     -------  
1                        book
2                        pen
3                        computer
4                        book
5                        pen
6                        mobile
7                        book
```

This is main table. i want result(item count is >1) as

```
ID                       ITEM                       COUNT
----                    -------                    -------
1                        BOOK                         3
4                        BOOK                         3
7                        BOOK                         3
2                        PEN                          2
5                        PEN                          2
```

**I am writing query as:**

```
SELECT ID,ITEM,COUNT(ITEM)  
FROM MAIN 
GROUP by ID,ITEM 
HAVING COUNT(ITEM)>1
ORDER BY ITEM
```

and getting result as:

```
ID                       ITEM                       COUNT
----                    -------                    -------
```

Comment: WHY ARE WE SHOUTING?!

Comment: Is the CAPS LOCK key on your keyboard stuck? If not, there's not reason to SHOUT AT US. Posting in ALL CAPS makes your question harder to read, and it won't get you answers any faster (and it's really annoying and rude). The Shift key exists for a reason - using properly upper and lower cased letters makes text easier to read. **USE IT**.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server??? The title and tags don't match. Retag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.ID, m.ITEM, m1.`COUNT`
FROM MAIN m
JOIN (
    SELECT ITEM, COUNT(*) AS `COUNT`
    FROM MAIN
    GROUP BY ITEM
    HAVING `COUNT` > 1
    ) m1
ON m.ITEM = m1.ITEM
ORDER BY m.ITEM, ID
```

Your problem was that you had both `ID` and `ITEM` in the `GROUP BY`. Since IDs are unique, you never had any duplicates.

The subquery is used to get the count for each item. Then you join it with the original table so you can show each ID separately.